# Interacting with gnome calendar via the cli -- adding and reading events

Tags: command-line, gnome

Is there a programmatic API to take actions in gnome calendar which you can do via the GUI?

Some example actions will be

1. Create an event
2. Fetch a list of events for today

I see that there is a `gnome-calendar` binary on my path,but it seems to have options to only launch the GUI app and nothing else.

I like how it's minimal in functionality, it seems to fit the unix philosophy of doing a thing and doing it well. However, I can't find support for the other part -- that simple tools are powerful only when composable.

Comment: Probably not, conform the very minimal, some would say "simplistic"  design of some Gnome applications, but there quite certainly will be a dbus interface.

Comment: gnome trashed their UI (now Mate) to be replaced by some monstrosity that is not more touch friendly, usable, better looking, intuitive. Give them points that it's working at all.